# Unintentionally remapped keys on a MacBook Air (2012)

Tags: keyboard, hardware, keybindings

One day my MacBook Air mysteriously remapped the 'U', 'I' and 'O' keys to all be the alt/option key. I've no idea what triggered this, I took it to the apple shop and it seems to stay that way when they did the hardware test. Does anyone know why this could be, and hopefully recommend a way of fixing it?

Comment: Does an external keyboard work OK?

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting the NVRAM and the SMC on your Mac then test those keys and see if they are still remapped.

**NVRAM aka PRAM**
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063

> How to reset NVRAM
>
> Shut down your Mac, then turn it on and immediately press and hold
>   these four keys together: Option, Command, P, and R. You can release
>   the keys after about 20 seconds, during which your Mac might appear to
>   restart.
>
> On Mac computers that play a startup sound, you can release the keys
>   after the second startup sound. On iMac Pro, you can release the keys
>   after the Apple logo appears and disappears for the second time.

**SMC (System Management Controller)** 
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295

> How to reset the SMC on Mac notebooks
>
> First, determine whether the battery is removable. Most older Mac
>   notebooks have removable batteries. Mac notebooks that have
>   nonremovable batteries include MacBook Pro (Early 2009 and later), all
>   models of MacBook Air, MacBook (Late 2009), and MacBook (Retina,
>   12-inch, Early 2015 and later). Learn more about Mac notebook
>   batteries.
>
> If the battery is nonremovable:
>
> 1. Choose Apple menu > Shut Down.
> 2. After your Mac shuts down, press Shift-Control-Option on the left side of the built-in keyboard, then press the power button at the same
>      time. Hold these keys and the power button for 10 seconds. If you have
>      a MacBook Pro with Touch ID, the Touch ID button is also the power
>      button.
> 3. Release all keys.
> 4. Press the power button again to turn on your Mac.
>
> If the battery is removable:
>
> 1. Shut down your Mac.
> 2. Remove the battery. If you need help removing the battery, contact
>      an Apple Authorized Service Provider or Apple Retail Store.
> 3. Press and hold the power button for 5 seconds.
> 4. Reinstall the battery.
> 5. Press the power button again to turn on your Mac.